# Esnachta in taam elyon

Tags: trop-cantillation, parashas-yisro, aseres-hadibros, vaeschanan

Except in Tehillim, Mishlei, and most of Iyov, the esnachta indicates the biggest break in a pasuk.  In the taam elyon in both Yisro and Vaetchanan, the second dibra is one pasuk, with the esnachta almost all the way at the end, before ועשה חסד לאלפים.

Why is the break there?  I would have thought it should be before כי אנכי ה' א-להיך א-ל קנא, but instead the segol, which is the second biggest break, is there.

The same is true in the case of Shabbos in Yisro - a simple understanding would put the esnachta on בשעריך, before כי ששת-ימים.  Instead, there's only a zakeif there.

Why is the break up so strange?

Comment: What makes you think those are bigger breaks?

Comment: @DonielF The one in Shabbos is in the middle of a pasuk in taam tachton and in the middle of the taam hamitzvah.  And the one in lo yihyeh is in the middle of a parallel structure (פקד...ועשה חסד).